# The graph of $3x + 4y = 12$. There is a shaded square whose 3 vertices are on coordinate axes...

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions

The diagram at below shows the graph of

$$3x + 4y = 12.$$

The shaded figure is a square, three of whose vertices are on the coordinate axes. The fourth vertex is on the line.

[image: The diagram]

Find

(a) the $x$- and $y$-intercepts of the line;

(b) the length of a side of the square.

I know how to find the $x$ and $y$ intercepts $(4,0)$ and $(0,3)$ (by plugging in $0$ for $x$ and $y$) And I have the equation to solve for part b : $4s+3s= 12$. ($s$ referring to side) but I do not know why that is the way to solve part b.

Comment: "The diagram at right"... Can you show is the diagram?

Comment: my apologies, I added it.

Comment: The vertex on the y-axis is (0, s) where s is the length of a side of the square and, since this is a square, the vertex on the x-axis is (s, 0).  That means that the fourth vertex is (s, s).  Since that vertex lies on the line 3x+ 4y= 12, we must have 3s+ 4s= 12.  Obviously, that is the same as 7s=  12.

Answer (score 1):

Let's call $s$ the lenght of the side of the square. Then you know that the right top point of the square has coordinates $(s,s)$.

You also know that the top right point of the square lies on the line, and you for every point $(x,y)$ on the line, you know that $3x+4y=12.$

Can you put these two pieces of knowledge together?

Comment: YES it is so obvious I am embarrassed. Thank you!

Comment: @user280680 Don't be embarrassed! Everyone was a beginner once! Also, if the question is answered, you can also accept my answer...